# Why is this bitmap not animating across the screen? Android App

Tags: java, android, graphics, bitmap

I'm trying to make a simple ball move across the screen. I have the ball as a bitmap, and I have strings set up for the x and y values. I have a small code saying, if x is less than width add 10, until its greater, then reset to 0. same for y. But the ball does not move on the screen, at all.

Why wont my ball move?

```
`package com.example.spader.gamer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;

import android.view.View;

/**
 * Created by Spader on 2/10/2016.
 */
public class drawingTheBall extends View {

    Bitmap bBall;

    int x, y;


    public drawingTheBall(Context context) {
        super(context);

        bBall = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bball);
        x = 0;
        y = 0;


    }



    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);



        Rect ourRect = new Rect();
        ourRect.set(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight() / 2);

        Paint blue = new Paint();
        blue.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        blue.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        canvas.drawRect(ourRect, blue);



        if (x < canvas.getWidth()){
            x += 10;

        }else{
            x = 0;
        }

        if (y < canvas.getHeight()){
            y += 10;
        }else{
            y = 0;
        }

        Paint p = new Paint();
        canvas.drawBitmap(bBall, x, y, p);
        invalidate();

    }
}
`
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ball won't move because the only responsibility of the draw() method is to use the given Canvas to make the view display what it's supposed to.  Android will call draw() when it's ready to show the contents of a view, and only then.  This usually happens after your view hierarchy goes through a layout pass or something invalidates your view.  Android does not call draw in a loop.

If you need animation, that logic should be managed by code that might live in your activity or some other sort of controller type object which makes sure that draw will eventually get called as often as you need to animate.  You can also perform basic animation of an entire view using [ViewPropertyAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html), but it looks like you want the view to handle all its own positioning and rendering of items.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am kinda new to programming so can you help me a little more in understanding your reply? How do I make the ondraw method happen over and over with my bitmap, so the image is repositioned?

Comment: Well, if you're new to programming overall, I would suggest instead following a tutorial for beginners that will get your acquainted with Java and Android.  What you're trying to do requires some existing knowledge of both, which is beyond the scope of a StackOverflow question.